# Can summon cast spells with longer casting time?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, summoning

Some summons have spells, like a [Djin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=212) with [Creation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=54) spell, which has 1 minute casting time. Neither [summoned rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=154) forbid from multiturn casting, nor [cast a spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=72) require having all 3 actions available.

The question is:
Can summoned Djin cast creation spell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Needs GM approval (but reasonably yes)

Yes, you can have your djinn cast Creation, assuming your GM agrees. [Summon Elemental](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=320) will allow you to keep the Djinn around exactly long enough to cast Creation, since it acts on the turn you summon it. You'll have to be in [Exploration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=522) or [Downtime](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=538) mode, since [spells with long casting times can't be cast in combat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=72). So things do get a bit fuzzy - because it's unclear how [minions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=109) ([which summoned creatures are](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=154)) interact with Exploration mode (as in nothing is explicitly stated). Since nothing is explicitly stated, we default to the rules on actions and reactions in Exploration Mode:

> Actions and Reactions: Though exploration isn’t broken into rounds, exploration activities assume the PCs are spending part of their time using actions, such as Seeking or Interacting. If they have specific actions they want to use, they should ask; [the GM] can decide whether the actions apply and whether to switch to encounter mode for greater detail. PCs can use any relevant reactions that come up during exploration mode.

So, does your GM allow minions to use actions in Exploration mode? It's never forbidden, and it makes sense; some animal companions (like the [Bat](https://2e.aonprd.com/AnimalCompanions.aspx?ID=18)) are given Stealth as a skill, which mostly has use in Exploration Mode. So technically we need GM permission, but all signs point to yes here.

The Djinn is more than able to do the casting time (focusing on the spell for **one minute**), and you'll be able to [sustain the spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=73) throughout. So all together, signs point to **yes, your Djinn can cast Creation**.

I don't see this as a balance issue, either - you're getting less value out of your summon than you would by having them cast a same-leveled spell in combat and also being able to take some hits or do other things.

### The Counterargument

The obvious counterargument is that "minions have two-thirds the actions so they take longer to cast these spells, which would invalidate your Djinn case (but not all theoretical cases). I find this unpersuasive because the rules do seem to allow Animal Companions to use actions in Exploration time (e.g. Stealth again). There's even some argument that Animal Companions can use Exploration Activities, since otherwise a group that is [Hustling](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=515) that had an animal companion would have to leave it behind or carry it! In neither of these cases does it make narrative or mechanical sense to make the animal companion 2/3 slower than the PCs, nor is there any rules support for doing so. Additionally, the spell asks for 1 minute of casting, not 30 actions. So the counterargument isn't really persuasive.